# React. Ошибка в консоли из-за activeClassName

Tags: reactjs, style

Вот мой код

```
import React from "react";
import s from "./Cars.module.css"

export default (props) => (
    <div className={s.cars} activeClassName={s.active}>
        <div className={s.car}>
            <p>Company: {props.company}</p>
            <p>Model: {props.model}</p>
            <p>Price: {props.price}$</p>
            <button onClick={props.onChangeTitle}>Click</button>
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

В консоли высвечивается ошибка:

`React does not recognize the activeClassName prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase activeclassname instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.`

Из за чего это может быть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет такого атрибута "activeClassName" у тега "div". У тега "Link" есть